# MySQL query order by multiple items

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Is it possible to order by multiple rows?

I want my users to be sorted by `last_activity`, but at the same time, I want the users with pictures to appear before the ones without

Something like this:

```
SELECT some_cols
FROM `prefix_users`
WHERE (some conditions)
ORDER BY last_activity, pic_set DESC;
```

Comment: Where and how are the pictures defined?

Comment: Tip for other people. If you leave off the ASC / DESC on 'last_activity' the default sort order can be ASC.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

```
SELECT some_cols
FROM prefix_users
WHERE (some conditions)
ORDER BY pic_set DESC, last_activity;
```

> **Note** that we can place `ASC` or `DESC` after each column (like above does for `pic_set`), or leave it to default (like above's `last_activity`-column).

Answer (score 19):

Sort by picture and then by activity:

```
SELECT some_cols
FROM `prefix_users`
WHERE (some conditions)
ORDER BY pic_set, last_activity DESC;
```

Comment: i dont understand, where does the DESC go?? behind every item?

Comment: Yes. You probably want to order the `last_activity` from newest to oldest. And if you explain how the pictures are defined (what the `pic_set` stands for), I could tell you how to sort this attribute too.

Comment: Alexander, I believe you can do `ORDER BY pic_set DESC, last_activity DESC` or `ORDER BY pic_set DESC, last_activity ASC` so sort direction for each column, default sort direction in mysql (with default configuration) is ASC.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT id, user_id, video_name
FROM sa_created_videos
ORDER BY LENGTH(id) ASC, LENGTH(user_id) DESC
```