# mysql order by two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I could solve this on php side, but I would like to use only one query:

I have this rows that represents categories and there list order and subcategory pathway:

```
 id   order pathway
  1     7     1
  2     5     2
  3     9     2/3
  4     0     4
  5     3     2/3/5
```

From that data I need to sort them primary by order number and then pathway to list subcategories inside there catetegory:

```
 id   order pathway
  4     0     4
  2     5     2
  3     9     2/3  
  5     3     2/3/5
  1     7     1
```

UPDATE:
simple sort by order, pathway doesn't work in this case.

First row that need to be outputed is ID:4 because it has the lowest order number
Then ID:2 because it has second lowest order number if we exclude ID:5 because it's inside categories 3 that is inside cat 2.

I also have column that represent category level (is it a main category or category inside some category and have deep) and column for category parent_id

Comment: Do you have any ideas about SQL? And, specifically, about `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: I don't see any discernable order by ascending/descending pattern in your expected output. MySQL (and most all RDBMS) ORDER BY clause is a fairly simple beast. If you need more advanced behaviour out of it, you're going to have to implement the sorting code yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876100/mysql-query-order-by-multiple-items

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY order, pathway
```

Comment: One can reverse the order by appending DESC (descending) resp. ASC: `ORDER BY "order" ASC, pathway DESC`. The word `order` is a keyword; better rename.

Comment: That doesn't sort subcategories inside there categories

Comment: I don´t get your tablestructure, categories are the first number of pathway and anything that followes are subcategories?

Comment: @sine, yes, I just updated original question

Comment: @Joop Eggen this is example data, it's not real table structure

Comment: oooh so you have hierarchical Data, I´m no MySQL Guru but afaik mysql doesn´t support CTE´s so you can´t do this with a single SQL-Statement stick with your PHP Solution ;-)