# MySQL and HTML: Ordering a row based on a specific value

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm working on a little downloads area of a website where people can submit different themes, and the community can rate them with a + or - 1 (very similar to Stack Overflow).

I currently am pulling data from a MySQL database - much of that isn't terribly important to the question - but here is what my final code and table looks like:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['votes'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['author'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['description'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I would like to order each table row based on the value of the `<td>` called `votes`.  I understand this is a bit broad since I don't have code supplied, but I've searched the web and found nothing about what I'm attempting to do.  I'm sure it can be done by modifying the `while` function, but I'm not sure how.

If it proves to be any help, my full PHP code is below:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('host','name','password');
mysql_select_db('database',$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM themer";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

echo '<table>';

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['votes'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['author'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['description'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

**EDIT:** I apparently was searching for the wrong stuff when I researched this - I didn't know mySQL had the functionality described in the answers below.  Now that I know what was up, this might be a possible duplicate - [mysql query order by multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876100/mysql-query-order-by-multiple-items)

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly you want it ordered?

Comment: Ordered from highest to lowest number

Comment: Also, whoever downvoted, I'd appreciate feedback on why.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM themer ORDER BY votes DESC`

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, can't believe it was that easy.  Thanks.

Comment: Its not your "while function" any way learn about ORDER BY clause in manuals of MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option is to pass the responsibility down to the database level. This is also most likely the best option since you can then add an index; database engines are quite good at querying and ordering results. Add [an `ORDER BY` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) to your query, making your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM themer
ORDER BY votes
```

To order this from highest to lowest, you'll need to reverse the sort order. Do this by adding a `DESC` keyword:

```
SELECT *
FROM themer
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

---

*Note: new code should really not be using the `mysql_` PHP functions anymore. They are deprecated, and [for good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Good alternatives include [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).*

Comment: Awesome, this did it.  I'll also do a duplicate search since I think I was searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: Konnichiwa! +1 for explaning about deprecated mysql_ maybe you should also suggest what to use.

Comment: Possible there's a dupe somewhere; I didn't look. I've linked to the MySQL documentation, it has a couple examples. You might want to pick up a book on SQL and database design/queries at some point as well.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Good suggestion. Added a couple of links.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM themer 
        ORDER BY ABS(votes) DESC';
```