# mysql: order the result by column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$qry="select * from table where category='car' or title='car' or description='car'";
```

but I want the output to list the rows by category first and then title and then description.

****Edit: actually I am using a like operator to search**

Example:

```
 id category title description   
  1    car 
  2    car
  3            car
  4            car
  5            car
  6                    car
```

is there any way other than using union?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for ORDER BY? Sorry but unclear..

Comment: I think order by will not work. if you think it will help to answer my question pllease post it

Comment: you can follow the Gordon answer... its better than to us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using `ORDER BY` with the right keys.  In MySQL, you can do:

```
ORDER BY (category = 'car') DESC,
         (title = 'car') DESC,
         (description = 'car') DESC
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context, with 0 for false and 1 for true.  So the `DESC` puts the true versions first.

You can also simplify the `WHERE` clause if you like:

```
WHERE 'car' IN (category, title, description)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get this result by using this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (category='car' OR title='car' OR description='car')
ORDER BY category = 'car' DESC,
title = 'car' DESC,
description = 'car' DESC
```

**How it works?**

It will set the orders of data in `DESC` by `sequentially` as mentioned in query. You can change the sequence as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` for multiple columns like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY category DESC, title DESC, description DESC
```

I have tried it and it [worked](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56f61/1).

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `WHERE` caluse I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this ,

SELECT * FROM table where 'car' IN (category, title, description)  ORDER BY category DESC, title DESC, description DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `ORDER BY` clause in your query.

```
    select *from table where category='car' or title='car' or description='car' ORDER BY category DESC, title DESC, description DESC
```

See this answer for reference. [mysql query order by multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876100/mysql-query-order-by-multiple-items)

Comment: Should be in descending order.

Comment: Also need a space after the `*`

Comment: Maybe but I like *from rather than * FROM. It takes time to enter the space :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query :

```
select * from table 
where category='car' or title='car' or description='car' 
order by 1 desc, 2 desc, 3 desc
```